# Opening file:// links in explorer through chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-explorer

I'm switching our company's preferred browser from IE to Chrome and I've run into a problem.

When opening `file://` links on our intranet, they open in chrome rather than explorer.

Is there any way to get `file://` links to open using explorer?

Comment: Which one is your default browser? Chrome likes to makes itself default at any opportunity

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue as well.

The reason behind it is security.

> The security model of Chrome prevents/blocks the user from being able
>   to open file:// links when the user selects (left clicks) the link, or
>   selects to open them in a new window (middle click).

You will have to use [an addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida) if you would like it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is how to register an application to a certain URL protocol, in your case `file://`. This question was asked earlier, see the link [1] below. I know it's an old question, but you might find some pointers there.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364895/register-an-application-to-a-url-protocol-all-browsers-via-installer

Comment: I've tried changing the program to open `file://` links to `explorer.exe` but chrome still opens them itself.